# How to highlight current active link with background color using divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I tried to make a menu using divs [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/haramizuki/80onLn21/1/)

This is my css:

```
#footer {
bottom:0px;
height:70px;
left:0px;
position:absolute;
width:100%!important;
z-index:100;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)!important;
}
#footer .menu {
height:54px;
color:#000;
}


.footerFloat {
   display:inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 min-width:200px;

}

.footerh4 {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
line-height: 20px;

}

.footertoptxt {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 14px;
}

.top25 {
margin-top: 20px;
}

.top30 {
margin-top: 30px;
}

a.footer-fill {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.clickable a {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
text-decoration:none;
z-index:10;
opacity: 0; 
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}

div.clickable {
position: relative;
height: 70px;
}

div.clickable:hover{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
color: #fff;
}
```

html here:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="menu">
<div class="footerFloat footerfill clickable">
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="footerh4 top30">Home</div>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat footerfill clickable">
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="footertoptxt top25">Lorem Ipsum in</div>
<div class="footerh4">Store Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat clickable">
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="footertoptxt top25">Lorem Ipsum in</div>
<div class="footerh4">Corporate Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat clickable">
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="footertoptxt top25">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="footerh4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to make the current opened link have a background of opaque black? Like when if I'm on 'Home' page, the home in the footer will have a background of opaque black, and so on.

I'm doing using this on a Wordpress website.

Apologies for my messy code. It's the only way I got it to look like how I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple jquery code to do this :

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer a").click(function() {
        $("#footer a").parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });      
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 color: #fff;   
}
```